# How to make count(*) query work in Hibernate from unmapped entities?

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql

I am new to Hibernate. And here I successfully used SQL query as is using session.createSQLQuery():

```
SELECT  t2.col1, t2.col2, t2.col3, t5.col4, t1.col5, t4.col6, t4.col7,        
        DECODE(t1.col8,null,t1.col9,t1.col8), t1.col10, t1.col11, t8.col12
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2   
  ON t1.xyz   = t2.xyz
JOIN table3 t3      
  ON t2.col3  = t3.col3 
LEFT JOIN view1 t4  
  ON t1.abc   = t4.abc1
LEFT JOIN view2 t5  
  ON t1.abc10 = t5.abc2 AND t5.xyz1 = 1
JOIN table6 t6      
  ON t2.abc8  = t6.abc9
JOIN table7 t7      
  ON t6.xyz2  = t7.xyz2
LEFT JOIN table8 t8 
  ON t2.col1  = t8.abc3 AND t8.abc5 = 'XYZ' AND t8.abc6 = 1234
WHERE t2.DISPLAY = 'true' 
  AND t2.abc4    = 0 
  AND t6.abc7    = 0 
  AND t2.col2    = 0
```

So I don't have all those entities Java objects. And no mapping xml file. But this query does not work when I use "SELECT COUNT(`*`) FROM " It is giving me an error "unexpected token ON". So how to fix select COUNT(*)? Thank you.

Comment: If you use only SELECT COUNT(*) without other fields, please use SELECT COUNT(t2.col1). Tell me if it's ok

Answer (score 0):

You need a group by to do COUNT(*).
group by the values you select and you should have your count ;)